# Is there a number keypad activity in android that I can launch?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there an activity that I can launch the Enter Password number pad as below? I'm building an application that should only be accessed by a person that knows the password.

http://www.mobilephone.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/App-Lock-Android.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There's not a specific Activity for this, but what you can use is the `android:inputType` and `android:password` attributes of an EditText.  If you create an activity with a simple layout that contains an EditText with `android:inputType="number"` and `android:password="true"`, you'll be on your way to simulating this behavior.  You'll probably want to do perform some other actions, such as restricting the number of characters, I'd suggest giving it a try and perhaps asking for more help once you've got some code to share and a more specific question.